# 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-webpages

```
        TextBox txtStatus = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox6") as TextBox;
        string strcn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection( strcn);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Associate_Table set [Status] = @Status where [Associate ID] =+Convert.ToInt32(id.Text)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        con.Close();
```

plz help getting error. I have no idea what, I done here
and the error is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'

Comment: Debug the code and you will see that the Sql you generate is incorrect. You are concatenating a string "+Convert.ToInt32(id.Text)" into the sql-clause. Also your code (when that is fixed) will be vulnerable to sql-injection. Please use parameters for each value, same way you use it with status.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **+** sign only for concatenating string values. Update your code by following snippet.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Associate_Table set [Status] = @Status where [Associate ID] = @AssociateID", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", txtStatus.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssociateID", Convert.ToInt32(id.Text));
```

Answer (score -1):

Put aout the parameter from the query string...

Something like :

```
SqlCommand cmd 
   = new SqlCommand("update Associate_Table 
                     set [Status] = @Status where [Associate ID] = " 
                    + Convert.ToInt32(id.Text), con);
```